# expr: non-integer argument while doing Arithmetic in Shell Script

Tags: bash, shell, cygwin, sh, ksh

When i'm trying to execute following line of code

```
#!/bin/sh
a=20
b=10
sum=`expr $a + $b` #(i thought i did wrong with ` so i put (') also to check but its becomes literals which gets printed as usual)
echo $sum
```

i'm getting the error

> expr: non-integer argument

Can someone tell me where it went wrong in this code because almost on every tutorial same thing was mentioned to do Arithmetic in Shell Script.

Edit: for those whose working i'm using CYGWIN terminal FYI. IS there any difference ?

Edit 2 : As mentioned in the comment by @ghoti Windows file ends with /r/n while unix ends with /n .. Since i'm writing my Script in windows platform while executing in Unix Platform , So when i'm removing back-tick its giving me error

> $'20\r': command not found

so definitely $a is changed into 20 but **\r** is resulting into error. So any ideas how to Short out this error ?

Comment: are you arguments really number? Also dont use backticks its discouraged.

Comment: Works for me in bash and dash, outputs `30`.

Comment: Does your script have CRLF line endings? Then you would have `expr 20\r + 10\r`

Comment: SMA no argument is not really number as Shell store things in String but isn't it where expr comes handy to do Arithmetic Evaluation

Comment: Not reproducible [here](http://ideone.com/DuE3BZ). Is this your real script?

Comment: glenn jackman i think yes because  when i removed backticks it was giving me error with such "20/r" : command not found so i guess yes

Comment: @n.m. yeah and i'm using CYGWIN Terminal BTW. IS there any difference ?

Comment: @AnkurAnand, in Windows, text files have lines that end with `\r\n`, whereas in unix they end in `\n`.  So yes, there is a difference.  Do you know how to proceed?

Comment: Also, `#!/bin/sh` means that you're running a Bourne or posix shell.  If you're using bash, then you're running it in compatibility mode.  You should use `#!/bin/bash` if you really want to write bash scripts.

Comment: and if you're reallly writing `bash` scripts, then you can use "modern" math processing provided in bash and ksh like `sum=$(( a + b ))`. Good luck to all.

Comment: @ghoti No i don't any any idea how to proceed .. can you help ?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error.
I did the following and issue resolved:

Go to Edit in notepad++, then selected EOL Conversion, then selected UNIX/OSX Format

Answer (score 0):

Your original code should work correctly. Even though, to make sure you don't have any issue with quotes, you can slightly modify it like that:

```
#!/bin/sh
a=20
b=10
sum=$(expr $a + $b)
echo $sum
```