# expr: non-integer argument error in Cygwin

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am using notepad++ editor and executing the shell script in Cygwin terminal.

```
x=5
y=6
z=`expr x + y`
echo $z
```

Following error is seen:

```
expr: non-integer argument
```

What is wrong with the script?

Comment: Aside from what varro correctly said: Why do you need `expr` here? Since you are using bash and integer arithmetic, a simple `((z=x+y))` would do.

Comment: Agreed, since I am new to shell, don't have the complete idea. So started with some basics. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to dereference the variables:

```
z=`expr $x + $y`
```

Also, make sure your script has POSIX line endings (LF), not DOS-style (CRLF) line endings.  (Use `dos2unix` or similar to convert.)

Comment: It works fine in Linux machine. But in cygwin still I see same error - "expr: non-integer argument". Looks like notepad++ editor adds some unwanted things. With ((z=x+y)), I am getting error as- "syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r'"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28965805/expr-non-integer-argument-while-doing-arithmetic-in-shell-script?rq=1
Found another link with same issue. Can someone help?

Comment: The link you mention points you to the problem - you probably have CRLF (DOS-style) line endings in your script.  You must convert the script to POSIX format, using, e.g., `dos2unix`.

Comment: Issue solved: Got to Edit in notepad++, then EOL Conversion, then select UNIX/OSX Format.